# Foreach into an array

Tags: javascript

I'm using `vue.js` and `lodash` to go through a list of events and to get the promoted events. I then want to push each event into a new object or array containing a new list of promoted events. However i'm getting new arrays of each of each object instead of getting each object into 1 array

```
       getPromotedEvents() {
            //get a list of promoted events
             _.forEach(this.events, (eventList) => {
                if(eventList.promote_event){
                    let arr = [];
                    arr.push(eventList)
                    console.log(arr);
                }
            });
        },


this returns [{}], [{}], [{}] instead of [{},{},{}]
```

Comment: Please try to move the `let arr = [];` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're reinstating the array **inside** the loop. Try this:

```js
getPromotedEvents() {
  let arr = [];
  //get a list of promoted events
  _.forEach(this.events, (eventList) => {
    if (eventList.promote_event) {
      arr.push(eventList)
      console.log(arr);
    }
  });
},
```